# Blend-Exchange not accepting v3.x files

Tags: discussion

I tried to upload a 3.0 version blend file into [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and got the message "All uploaded files must be in the blend file format".   It appears to not recognize post 2.93 file formats.

[image]

Comment: You should probably ask in Blender Meta

Comment: @Emir I'm guessing that Meta is some insider-known website of which I'm not familiar.  Do you have a link where I can Q&A my problem ?

Comment: @Emir thanks for your help on this !

Comment: @Timaroberts -- suggest to try again after cache cleaning perhaps. What "cache" are you referring to?  Cookies?  I just tried again with a simple 3.0 file and still no love.

Comment: What happens if you try with another Browser?

Comment: Great ... I thought I'm the only one :) https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/issues/56#issuecomment-1030765447

Answer (score 5):

I've disabled blend file validation for now, resolving this issue. See https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/issues/56 for details.

If someone is handy with PHP and wants to take a crack at handling the new blend file format changes, I'd love a community contribution. It will probably be a little while before I can do this work myself.

Comment: Yet again today, it was not accepting my files :-(

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered this error when trying to upload a compressed file from the question [Geonodes: when creating an instance, get index from instancer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/245996/60486)

Turning off compression solved the issue.

Just tried again with the compressed file:

[image]

Comment: compressed as by an external program like winzip?  has that ever worked?

Comment: @MartyFouts compressed as in the setting in the save dialog, which I always used to save space on the server: https://i.imgur.com/EchlR84.png

Comment: The developers changed the compression algorithm for 3.0  blend-exchange needs an update to be able to handle the new compression algorithm.  Perhaps @GiantCowFilms is already working on it.

Comment: Thanks for info! I am going to try and get a fix out for this as soon as I can (my life is pretty hectic right now). If someone wants to take a shot at this I am also happy to accept a pull request.

Comment: Thanks Markus ... great to know :)

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Thank you for looking into this once you are able to. Blend-Exchange is indispensable to us. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As of this afternoon, I was able to upload a 3.0 file, using Chrome on Windows 10. I then went to the [Blend-Exchange github repository](https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange) and verified that there was no change made.  Glancing at the source, it looks like Blend-Exchange does very minimal checking to see if a file is really a blend file; so I suspect you ran into a server internal glitch that got reported incorrectly.

Are you still having the problem?  If so, I recommend filling out their Help request.

Comment: Thanks Marty am going to enter a request.  Can upload only pre-3.0 files, same in Firefox and Chrome on Win-10.

Comment: Okay while filing a request I just got "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.".  I'm chucking and not going to pull my hair out.  Ah it worked the second time I tried.  Whew!

Comment: That's very weird.  Basically all they do is look at the header to see if it looks like a blender file, so I don't know why you're getting errors.

Comment: It just started working for 3.0 files for me now, perhaps about 30 minutes after I posted the problem report.  Perhaps coincidental -- don't know .

Comment: @james_t Were you able to successfully upload the file? I'm guessing this may have been a temporary issue (The 26mb file size might have been a bit much for my server). When I have some free time I will take a look and see if I can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms -- thanks for maintaining this for us!   I had also tried with an almost empty startup file 0.1 Mb and had failures.   Thankfully it cleared for me.  Its very useful.

Comment: The 3.0 upload error has re-appeared since yesterday. @GiantCowFilms

Comment: @GiantCowFilms  I keep intermittently running into this problem; again today I got the same error message.   Why does this keep happening?

Answer (score 1):

Today's error du jour is:

[image]

Comment: @GiantCowFilms -- yet more issues.